# Flutter Webview : Alternate screen for inital url not loaded

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I need an alternate screen when my webpage not loaded;

Note: Webpage was hosting on localhost, so internet connectivity based changeover not possible.

Query: Can we ping IP and change over the screens

Any Possible ways to achieve this ?

** main.dart **

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'flutter webview',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('flutter webview'),
          ),
          body: WebView(
              initialUrl: "http://192.168.29.8/public/_weblogin.html",
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can change the design onWebResourceError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view alternative designs on `onWebResourceError`
full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomeView(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  bool isError = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          if (!isError)
            WebView(
              initialUrl: 'http://192.168.29.8/public/_weblogin.html',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebResourceError: (error) => setState(() {
                isError = true;
              }),
            ),
          if (isError) const Center(child: Text("WEB PAGE ERROR")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I am tried this code, it replaces the error screen with black screen

Not showing that text 

Displaying only white blank screen

Comment: Maybe you are not replacing the code correctly. I edited the answer with full main.dart file code.